# PyTorch missing gradient in intermediate node

Tags: pytorch

I've read a couple other posts that by default intermediate tensors do not maintain their gradients so you need to set `requires_grad=True` and that in order to use them when back propagating you need to use `retain_grad()`, however I can't grok why in the example below the coefficients.grad is always None?

```py
def solvePolynomial(coefficients, x):
    return sum(coefficients[j] * (x**j) for j in range(len(coefficients)))

coefficients = torch.randn(2, requires_grad=True)
coefficients.retain_grad() # this seems to have no effect on the last line failing
predicted = torch.tensor([solvePolynomial(coefficients, x) for x in xs])
loss = ((predicted - ys)**2).mean()
loss.requires_grad() # I believe this is required? the next line fails without it saying: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
loss.backward()
coefficients -= 0.01 * coefficients.grad # this always fails, coefficients.grad is always NoneType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are several issues here.

Most importantly, creating a new tensor using `torch.tensor` like this:

```
predicted = torch.tensor([solvePolynomial(coefficients, x) for x in xs])
```

breaks the computational graph that's used to backprop the loss.
Concretely:

```
a = torch.arange(0, 1, 0.01, requires_grad=True)
b = 3 * torch.arange(0, 1, 0.01, requires_grad=True)
c = a * b # OK
d = torch.tensor(a * b) # BAD
```

Further points:

`loss.requires_grad()` will fail because `b.requires_grad` is a boolean variable, not a function (strictly, not a callable) and setting it here is not needed anyway since it will have a gradient because of how it's defined.

`coefficients -= 0.01 * coefficients.grad` fails even if there is a gradient, because it's an in-place operation. Instead, use
`coefficients = coefficients - 0.01 * coefficients.grad`

Less important points:
`coefficients.retain_grad()` is not needed because `coefficients` is a leaf node in the computation graph anyway, so it will store a gradient.

Also, using python list comprehensions and iterations is not *wrong* but is ill-advised. It is almost always faster to use matrix and vector operations instead of for loops, explicit or implicit.

Bringing it all together, the same code would be better written as:

```
import torch


def solvePolynomial(coefficients, x):
    x_powers = x.unsqueeze(1) ** torch.arange(coefficients.numel())
    return x_powers @ coefficients


xs = torch.arange(0, 20, 1, dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)
ys = 3 * torch.clone(xs)

coefficients = torch.randn(2, requires_grad=True)
predicted = solvePolynomial(coefficients, xs)
loss = ((predicted - ys)**2).mean()
loss.backward()
coefficients = coefficients - 0.01 * coefficients.grad
```